# How can I assign the contents of a .txt file to a string variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, text-files

I have a text file path stored in a variable called `settings_data_path` and I want to take whatever is in that text file and put it into a string variable, in this instance, `limited_n_ints` . So I opened the file and put it in a variable using

```
settings_data = open(settings_data_path, "r")
limited_n_ints = (settings_data.read())
print(limited_n_ints)
settings_data.close()
```

Whenever I open the data path with w+ and write something in the file, everything worked fine. However, when I print `limited_n_ints`, nothing shows up. Does anyone know how to store this file in a variable?

Comment: If this code prints nothing, that means the file was empty.

Comment: Above code is correct, it's printing the content of the text file for me

Comment: @JohnGordon the file is not empty, I checked it before trying to read it, and the file path is correct.

Comment: I stand by my statement.  If that code does not raise an error and just prints nothing, then the file was empty.  If you viewed the file in notepad and it had contents, then that wasn't the same file being opened in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
setting_data = open('inventory.4.txt', 'r')
lines = setting_data.readlines()
limited_n_ints = ''
for i in lines:
  limited_n_ints = limited_n_ints + i
print(limited_n_ints)
```